# Poisson process order statistics identity is incorrect?

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Let $X(t)$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ and $W_k$ be the $k$-th waiting time and $U_k$ be iid uniform random variables on $[0,t]$.  Prove: $$E\left[ \sum_{k = 1}^{n}e^{-\beta W_k} | X(t) = n \right] = E\left[ \sum_{k = 1}^{n}e^{-\beta U_k} \right].$$

I can see that $$E\left[ \sum_{k = 1}^{n}e^{-\beta W_k} | X(t) = n \right] = \sum_{w_1, \dots, w_n} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{-\beta w_k} \right )P(W_1 = w_1, \dots, W_n = w_n | X(t) = n)$$ and since $$P(W_1 = w_1, \dots, W_n = w_n | X(t) = n) = n!t^{-n} = P(U_{(1)} = w_1, \dots, U_{(n)} = w_n)$$

we have $$\sum_{w_1, \dots, w_n} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{-\beta w_k} \right )P(W_1 = w_1, \dots, W_n = w_n | X(t) = n) = \sum_{w_1, \dots, w_n} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{-\beta w_k} \right )n!t^{-n} $$ but

$$\sum_{w_1, \dots, w_n} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{-\beta w_k} \right )n!t^{-n} \neq \sum_{w_1, \dots, w_n} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{-\beta w_k} \right )t^{-n} = E\left[ \sum_{k = 1}^{n}e^{-\beta U_k}   \right]$$.

---

Am I miss understanding something here?  This seems like a contradiction.

Comment: The equalities for your waiting times are not really sensible since the waiting times of a Poisson process are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. So, the probability that any of them **equals** a certain value is zero.

Comment: Waiting times $W_k$ are defined here as the time until the $k-$th occurrence not the time between occurrences, so they should be Gamma distributed not exponential.